# Firebase async message not received

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Firebase Admin SDK set up with my backend service in order to notify mobile app about certain events. To deliver required data I send the events as data messages and retrieve them in `onMessageReceived` callback on the Android app side. It works fine unless I try to send an event asynchronously - in such case `onMessageReceived` isn't triggered at all. However, sending it in synchronous way causes no problems and the notification shows up on Android device within a second. The only difference is a method that I use to send the message:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message) // works perfectly
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message) // won't work
```

Is there any additional set up required to send FCM notifications asynchronously?

Comment: The call to the Firebase servers happens asynchronously in that second case. If it doesn't work, it sounds likely that the environment in which you run the code stops the call before it completes. Can you show the minimal **complete** code with context (where you have this snippet) that is needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If I simply create Message object in main function and send it with `send` and `sendAsync` then the same thing happens. I'm not sure what kind of informations would be helpful to track the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so basically I was testing FCM notifications without starting actual web service and main method was ending its execution before request to Firebase was completed. Sending event from within web service or putting main thread to sleep for a short amount of time solves the issue and the notification is properly delivered to mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get()
```

`sendAsync()` returns `ApiFuture<String>` which you might have missed.

Comment: This is equivalent to posting notification synchronously.